# Count number of tokens matching a pattern in a string

Tags: c#, c++, regex, pattern-matching

A method to count number of tokens matching a pattern in a string.

token is a "$" followed by "$$", there can be any number of characters between "$" and "$$".

Eg: `"$123$$, $ab$$, $qqwe123$$`

input string could be `"$122$$dddd$1aasds$$"`.

The output of the method should be 2 for the above string.

Programming Language could C# or C++.

here is the code I came up with but trying to find the best way possible:

```
static int CalculateTokenCount()
        {
            string s = "$ab$$ask$$$$123$$";
            int tokenCount = 0;
            bool foundOneDollar = false;
            bool foundSecondDollar = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                return tokenCount;
            }
            for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == '$' && !foundOneDollar)
                {
                    foundOneDollar = true;
                    continue;
                }

                if (foundOneDollar)
                {
                    if (s[i] == '$' && !foundSecondDollar)
                    {
                        foundSecondDollar = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (foundSecondDollar)
                {
                    if (s[i] == '$')
                    {
                        tokenCount++;
                    }  
                    foundSecondDollar = false;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(tokenCount);
            return tokenCount;
        }
```

Comment: Excellent problem. You have my go ahead to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression

```
\$.*?\$\$
```

This detects *any* number of characters in between, even zero characters. If you need at least one character replace `*` with `+`.

As @astander already said, to retrieve the count of matches use `Regex.Matches`

```
string input = "$122$$dddd$1aasds$$";
string pattern = @"\$.*?\$\$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
int count = matches.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using something like

[Regex.Matches Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx)

> Searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a regular
>   expression.

Also maybe have a look at [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: This could be better as a _comment_ IMO.